# Using Templates within a Kendo TreeView during rendering(Razor View)

Tags: templates, razor, treeview, kendo-ui

I would like to insert an extra hidden Kendo control (textbox, dropdown, etc.) beside every single item in the treeview. In Telerik Treeview, I used

**UPDATED:**

```
telerikTreeview.Template.InlineTemplate =@<text>  @(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete().Name("test1"))  </text>;
```

I was able to insert a control beside a treeview item during rendering.

Is this possible for Kendo Treeview?It seems like it has no InlineTemplate function. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that Kendo still supports the Inline Template. It just doesnt came out in the intellisence and and in their documentation. Dunno what happened there. But when I tried this code, it worked!

```
   kendoTreeview.Template.InlineTemplate = @<text>
     @(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete().Name("test1")) 
   </text>;
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, did you try the Template method?

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
    .Name("treeview")
    .DataTextField("Name")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Read(read => read
            .Action("Employees", "TreeView")
        )
    )
    .Template("<input type='text' /> ")
)
```

Comment: Yes i've tried that. But what I'm really trying to achieve is to render a Kendo control inside a treeview item. I apologize if I didnt say it clear. I've updated my question.Thank you @Pechka.